# Flattening an Iterable<Iterable<T>> in Guava

Tags: java, collections, guava, flatten

Is there a `flatten` method in Guava - or an easy way to convert an `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` to an `Iterable<T>`?

I have a `Multimap<K, V>` [sourceMultimap] and I want to return all values where the key matches some predicate [keyPredicate]. So at the moment I have:

```
Iterable<Collection<V>> vals = Maps.filterKeys(sourceMultimap.asMap(), keyPredicate).values();

Collection<V> retColl = ...;
for (Collection<V> vs : vals) retColl.addAll(vs);
return retColl;
```

I've looked through the Guava docs, but nothing jumped out. I am just checking I've not missed anything. Otherwise, I'll extract my three lines into a short flatten generic method and leave it as that.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [Iterables.concat method](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)) satisfies that requirement:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> concat(Iterable<? extends Iterable<? extends T>> inputs)
```

Comment: I would guess this is because this is only one level concatenation, not really flatten:)

Comment: Also if a collection is being generated from a guava transform, you can use FluentIterable transformAndConcat: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)

Answer (score 4):

As of Java 8, you can do this without Guava.  It's a bit clunky because [Iterable doesn't directly provide streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23114015/3614835), requiring the use of StreamSupport, but it doesn't require creating a new collection like the code in the question.

```
private static <T> Iterable<T> concat(Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> foo) {
    return () -> StreamSupport.stream(foo.spliterator(), false)
        .flatMap(i -> StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false))
        .iterator();
}
```

Comment: Does not fit my needs, because my iterator is lazy, but all lazyness is lost when convert such an iterator to stream.

Comment: @odiszapc I'm not sure what you mean.  Iterable.spliterator() just returns a Spliterator wrapping Iterable.iterator(); no elements are drawn until the stream's terminal operation begins.  Similarly, StreamSupport.stream is explicitly documented not to begin querying the spliterator until the terminal operation begins.  So I think you're saying your top-level _iterable_ is lazy, and you want to delay calling iterator() on it?  In that case, use the StreamSupport.stream overload taking a supplier (`StreamSupport.stream(() -> foo.spliterator(), false)`).

Comment: @odiszapc Otherwise, I'd be interested in a minimal example reproducing why this answer doesn't work, if you have time to make one, because I'll learn something from it.