# Why does Iterable<T> not provide stream() and parallelStream() methods?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, iterable

I am wondering why the `Iterable` interface does not provide the `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods. Consider the following class:

```
public class Hand implements Iterable<Card> {
    private final List<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int capacity;

    //...

    @Override
    public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```

It is an implementation of a *Hand* as you can have cards in your hand while playing a Trading Card Game.

Essentially it wraps a `List<Card>`, ensures a maximum capacity and offers some other useful features. It is better as implementing it directly as a `List<Card>`.

Now, for convienience I thought it would be nice to implement `Iterable<Card>`, such that you can use enhanced for-loops if you want to loop over it. (My `Hand` class also provides a `get(int index)` method, hence the `Iterable<Card>` is justified in my opinion.)

The `Iterable` interface provides the following (left out javadoc):

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();

    default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        for (T t : this) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }

    default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
    }
}
```

Now can you obtain a stream with:

```
Stream<Hand> stream = StreamSupport.stream(hand.spliterator(), false);
```

So onto the real question:

- Why does `Iterable<T>` not provide a default methods that implement `stream()` and `parallelStream()`, I see nothing that would make this impossible or unwanted?

A related question I found is the following though: [Why does Stream<T> not implement Iterable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129762/why-does-streamt-not-implement-iterablet)
Which is oddly enough suggesting it to do it somewhat the other way around.

Comment: I guess this is a good question for the [Lambda Mailing List](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev).

Comment: Why is it odd to want to iterate over a stream? How else could you possibly `break;` an iteration? (Ok, `Stream.findFirst()` might be a solution, but that might not fulfill all needs...)

Comment: See also [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk) for practical workarounds.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

This was not an omission; there was detailed discussion on the EG list in June of 2013.

The definitive discussion of the Expert Group is rooted at [this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-June/001910.html).

While it seemed "obvious" (even to the Expert Group, initially) that `stream()` seemed to make sense on `Iterable`, the fact that `Iterable` was so general became a problem, because the obvious signature:

```
Stream<T> stream()
```

was not always what you were going to want. Some things that were `Iterable<Integer>` would rather have their stream method return an `IntStream`, for example.  But putting the `stream()` method this high up in the hierarchy would make that impossible.  So instead, we made it really easy to make a `Stream` from an `Iterable`, by providing a `spliterator()` method. The implementation of `stream()` in `Collection` is just:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Any client can get the stream they want from an `Iterable` with:

```
Stream s = StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false);
```

In the end we concluded that adding `stream()` to `Iterable` would be a mistake.

Comment: I see, first of all, thanks a lot for answering the question. I am still curious though why an `Iterable<Integer>` (I think you are talking about?) would want to return an `IntStream`. Would the iterable then not rather be a `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt`? Or do you perhaps mean another usecase?

Comment: Maybe, but you don't really know that either.  Iterable is just too general; any default methods we add to Iterable implicitly constrains the contract of Iterable (worse, after the fact).  We made it easy to get a stream from an Iterable, by exposing spliterator() (which itself is a generalization of Iterator, so this  is not much of a stretch.)  But prudence dictated that we stop there.

Comment: Just noting that the last code sample does not compile AFAICT. The supplier variation takes three arguments, not one.

Comment: I find it odd that the above logic was supposedly applied to Iterable (I can't have stream() because someone might want it to return IntStream) whereas an equal amount of thought wasn't given to adding the exact same method to Collection (I might want my Collection<Integer>'s stream() to return IntStream also.) Whether it were present on both or absent on both, people would probably have just gotten on with their lives, but because it's present on one and absent on the other, it becomes quite a glaring omission...

Comment: Composition over inheritance.

Comment: Why couldn't `Iterable` have `stream()`, then implementors can add `intStream()` if applicable? Also, I suspect the cases where the issue you describe would occur are rare.

Comment: Brian McCutchon: That makes more sense to me. It sounds like people just got tired of arguing and decided to play it safe.

Comment: While this makes sense, is there a reason why there isn't an alternative static `Stream.of(Iterable)`, which would at least make the method reasonably discoverable by reading the API documentation -- as somebody who has never really worked with the internals of Streams I'd never even *looked* at `StreamSupport`, which is described in the documentation as providing "low-level operations" that are "mostly for library writers".

Comment: I totally agree with Jules. a static method Stream.of(Iteratable iter) or Stream.of(Iterator iter) should be added, instead of StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false);

Comment: Agree with Jules, Brian M., skiwi, and user_3380739 -- as someone coming back to Java after many, many years of C#, this seems like an obvious omission. Also, `spliterator` -- seriously, that's what it's called? Sounds like a 3rd party JS library to me!

Comment: Why does ```java.util.stream``` and ```java.util.function``` have special treatment for primitives? We have ```IntStream``` and ```IntUnaryOperator``` etc. but not ```IntList``` or ```IntIterable``` etc. Then there wouldn't be the problem of ```Iterable<Integer>``` wanting ```IntStream``` return type.

Comment: @wilmolI'm also wondering why Java Collections Framework has without specialization for primitives as Stream and Function do.

Comment: "This was not an omission" Perhaps super pedantic, but it's definitely an omission.  It's just an intentional omission, not an accidental one.

Answer (score 26):

I did an investigation in several of the project lambda mailing lists and I think I found a few interesting discussions.

I have not found a satisfactory explanation so far. After reading all this I concluded it was just an omission. But you can see here that it was discussed several times over the years during the design of the API.

**Lambda Libs Spec Experts**

I found a discussion about this in the [Lambda Libs Spec Experts mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-libs-spec-experts):

Under [Iterable/Iterator.stream()](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001528.html) Sam Pullara said:

> I was working with Brian on seeing how limit/substream
>   functionality[1] might be implemented and he suggested conversion to
>   Iterator was the right way to go about it. I had thought about that
>   solution but didn't find any obvious way to take an iterator and turn
>   it into a stream. It turns out it is in there, you just need to first
>   convert the iterator to a spliterator and then convert the spliterator
>   to a stream. So this brings me to revisit the whether we should have
>   these hanging off one of Iterable/Iterator directly or both.
>
> My suggestion is to at least have it on Iterator so you can move
>   cleanly between the two worlds and it would also be easily
>   discoverable rather than having to do:
>
> Streams.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator,
>   Spliterator.ORDERED))

And then [Brian Goetz responded](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001530.html):

> I think Sam's point was that there are plenty of library classes that
>   give you an Iterator but don't let you necessarily write your own
>   spliterator.  So all you can do is call
>   stream(spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator)).  Sam is suggesting that we
>   define Iterator.stream() to do that for you.
>
> I would like to keep the stream() and spliterator() methods as being
>   for library writers / advanced users.

[And later](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001533.html)

> "Given that writing a Spliterator is easier than writing an Iterator,
>   I would prefer to just write a Spliterator instead of an Iterator (Iterator is so 90s :)"
>
> You're missing the point, though.  There are zillions of classes out
>   there that *already* hand you an Iterator.  And many of them are not
>   spliterator-ready.

**Previous Discussions in Lambda Mailing List**

This may not be the answer you are looking for but in the [Project Lambda mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev) this was briefly discussed. Perhaps this helps to foster a broader discussion on the subject.

In the words of Brian Goetz under [Streams from Iterable](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-December/007131.html):

> Stepping back...
>
> There are lots of ways to create a Stream.  The more information you 
>   have about how to describe the elements, the more functionality and 
>   performance the streams library can give you.  In order of least to
>   most  information, they are:
>
> Iterator
>
> Iterator + size
>
> Spliterator
>
> Spliterator that knows its size
>
> Spliterator that knows its size, and further knows that all sub-splits
>   know their size.
>
> (Some may be surprised to find that we can extract parallelism even
>   from  a dumb iterator in cases where Q (work per element) is
>   nontrivial.)
>
> If Iterable had a stream() method, it would just wrap an Iterator with
>   a  Spliterator, with no size information.  But, most things that are 
>   Iterable *do* have size information.  Which means we're serving up 
>   deficient streams.  That's not so good.
>
> One downside of the API practice outlined by Stephen here, of
>   accepting  Iterable instead of Collection, is that you are forcing
>   things through a  "small pipe" and therefore discarding size
>   information when it might be  useful.  That's fine if all you're doing
>   to do is forEach it, but if you  want to do more, its better if you
>   can preserve all the information you  want.
>
> The default provided by Iterable would be a crappy one indeed -- it 
>   would discard size even though the vast majority of Iterables do know 
>   that information.

**Contradiction?**

Although, it looks like the discussion is based on the changes that the Expert Group did to the initial design of Streams which was initially based on iterators.

Even so, it is interesting to notice that in a interface like Collection, the stream method is defined as:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
   return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Which could be the exact the same code being used in the Iterable interface.

So, this is why I said this answer is probably not satisfactory, but still interesting for the discussion.

**Evidence of Refactoring**

Continuing with the analysis in the mailing list, it looks like the splitIterator method was originally in the Collection interface, and at some point in 2013 they moved it up to Iterable.

[Pull splitIterator up from Collection to Iterable](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010419.html).

**Conclusion/Theories?**

Then chances are that the lack of the method in Iterable is just an omission, since it looks like they should have moved the stream method as well when they moved the splitIterator up from Collection to Iterable.

If there are other reasons those are not evident. Somebody else has other theories?

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I disagree with the reasoning there. At the moment that you override the `spliterator()` of the `Iterable`, then all issues there are fixed, and you can trivially implement `stream()` and `parallelStream()`..

Comment: @skiwi That's why I said this is probably not the answer. I am just trying to add to the discussion, because it is difficult to know why the expert group made the decisions they did. I guess all we can do is try to do some forensics in the mailing list and see if we can come up with any reasons.

Comment: @skiwi I reviewed other mailing lists and found more evidence for the discussion and perhaps some ideas that help to theorize some diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I should really learn how to efficiently split through those mailing lists. It would help if they could be visualized in some... modern way, like a forum or something, because reading plain text emails with quotes in them is not exactly efficient.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the size you could use `java.util.Collection` which provides the `stream()` method:

```
public class Hand extends AbstractCollection<Card> {
   private final List<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();
   private final int capacity;

   //...

   @Override
   public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
       return list.iterator();
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return list.size();
   }
}
```

And then:

```
new Hand().stream().map(...)
```

I faced the same problem and was surprised that my `Iterable` implementation could be very easily extended to an `AbstractCollection` implementation by simply adding the `size()` method (luckily I had the size of the collection :-)

You should also consider to override `Spliterator<E> spliterator()`.