# Simplest way to stream an iterator

Tags: java, iterator, java-8, java-stream, iterable

Say you want to stream the elements of an iterator; let's use a concrete example of a `Scanner`, which implements `Iterator<String>`.

Given an `Iterator`, say:

```
// Scanner implements Iterator<String>
Iterator<String> scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Options to create a `Stream<String>` from it are the clunky:

```
StreamSupport.stream(
  Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(scanner, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
```

or the slightly more terse, but obtuse:

```
 StreamSupport.stream(
  ((Iterable<String>) () -> new Scanner(System.in)).spliterator(), false);
```

Is there a factory method somewhere in the JDK that returns a `Stream<T>` given an `Iterator<T>`?

Comment: You confused me by saying `new Scanner(System.in); // it's an Iterable<String>`

Comment: There is no simpler way but is this really that common that a simpler way is required?

Comment: @holger because `class Scanner implements Iterator<String>` and yes, I often want to stream the elements of an iterator (not just scanner of course, that's just an example of an Itsrator that isn't a Collection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23177907/829571

Comment: For what it's worth, regarding Scanner, [https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072722](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072722).

Comment: @Bohemian: to me it seems that I can count the examples of `Iterator`s, not being produced by an `Iterable`, with one hand, `Scanner` being the most prominent one (though I even have little use for that class, as, when I use regular expressions, I usually need more control over the operation). As it seems that it will get special treatment in the next Java version anyway, which real-life examples are left then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java8 Iterator to Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/java8-iterator-to-stream)

Answer (score 11):

I would simply use `Stream.generate(iterator::next)`. Yes, it is an infinite stream, but so is the scanner from `System.in`, unless you know how many lines you're asking for in which case it's easy enough to use

```
Stream.generate(iterator::next).limit(numLines);
```

This prevents the iterator from having to be iterated twice (once as the iterator, once as the stream).

If you need a sized stream without knowing how big it will be, but don't want to clutter your code just create a utility method that explicitly takes an `Iterable<T>`:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterable<T> it){
    return StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false);
}
```

It ends up being more legible than trying to cram it all on one line, and
then you can just call `stream(()->iterator);` or `stream(()->new Scanner(System.in));`

You can add the second convenience method easily enough, too:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> it){
    return stream(()->it);
}
```

enabling you to call `stream(iterator);` or `stream(new Scanner(System.in));`

Although, if I were going to read `System.in` into a stream, I'd probably use a Reader rather than a Scanner anyway:

```
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines();
```