# How do I convert a for loop to a stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I've learned a little bit about streams and know they can be used instead of loops. For this toy example, I'm using a graph database to store a set of Strings. The dB stores them as vertices. I'd like to retrieve those vertices and convert them to Strings, using a stream, instead. Each vertex has a set of properties; I give it a key and it returns a value. If a vertex has the property I'm looking for, I add it to the list. If it doesn't I store the vertex iD.

I have a for loop but I'm not sure how to use a stream instead. Here is the code:

```
public List<String> getItems() throws Exception {
    Iterable<Vertex> myNodes = graph.getVertices();

    List<String> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

    // maybe there is a way to use stream API instead?
    for(Vertex v : myNodes)
    {
      String value = v.getId().toString();
      if(v.getPropertyKeys().contains(key))
      {
         value = v.getProperty(key);
      }

      myItems.add(value);
    }

    return myItems;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sagar Rohankar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39795034/4105457) pointed out in his answer, you need to get the `Spliterator` from your `Iterable`. Then your task is a simple one-liner:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(graph.getVertices().spliterator(), false)
    .map(v -> v.getPropertyKeys().contains(key) ? v.getProperty(key) : v.getId().toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this SO thread. [Convert Iterable to Stream using Java 8 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932061/convert-iterable-to-stream-using-java-8-jdk)

In short, you have to use `StreamSupport#stream`, passing the `spliterator`, then use `map` to convert it into string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the Iterables into a Stream, to do this you can leveragae StreamSupport.

This post have a nice explanation 
[Why does Iterable<T> not provide stream() and parallelStream() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods)

You can use something like this:

```
StreamSupport.stream(graph.getVertices().spliterator(),false)
    .map(g -> g.getProperty(key))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```