# Java 9 Stream.iterate​(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next) call's hasNext after calling next

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

My understanding is it needs to check `hasNext` and then if it's `true`, then call the next method to get the element in the iterator.

*Issue:*

It calls `hasNext` after retrieving the element, In my case, the last element is retrieved using next and checks for `hasNext` then it returns `false` and the loop ends. So I process `N-1` elements instead of `N` elements.

Alternatively, I have used the below code.

```
Stream.generate(() -> j)
    .takeWhile(SlidingWindow::hasNextTimePeriod)
    .map(slider -> slider.next())
```

Reproducing Code :

```
@Slf4j
class Java9StreamTest {

    @Test
    void testStream() {

        final SlidingWindows slidingWindows = new SlidingWindows();

        Stream.iterate(slidingWindows.next(), j -> slidingWindows.hasNext(), j -> slidingWindows.next())
                .forEach(value -> log.info("{}", value));
    }
}

class SlidingWindows {
    private final List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
    private int count = 0;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return count < list.size();
    }

    public String next() {
        final String result = list.get(count);
        count = count + 1;
        return result;
    }    
}
```

*Output :*

```
20:20:03.485 [main] INFO mohan.stream.Java9StreamTest - A
20:20:03.489 [main] INFO mohan.stream.Java9StreamTest - B
```

Missing last element `C`

It works like a `for` loop, It's misleading in Java API to say `hasNext` and `next` in Docs.

What is equivalent to the below code in Streams?

```
 while(slidingWindows.hasNext()) { 
    final String next = slidingWindows.next(); 
    log.info("{}", next); 
 }
```

Comment: Note, as documented, `iterate` works like a `for` loop. It starts with a seed value, tests if the value meets the condition, computes the next value, tests if the new value meets the condition, and so on. As long as the condition is met, the "loop body" is entered. So, `iterate` must grab the next value before it can test if the condition is still met.

Comment: @Slaw  - You are right, it works like a `for` loop, It's misleading in Java API to say hasNext and next in Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [`Stream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) utilizes `for` loop under the hood:

> Stream.iterate should produce the same sequence of elements as
> produced by the corresponding for-loop:
>
> ```
>  for (T index=seed; hasNext.test(index); index = next.apply(index)) {
>      ...
>  }
> ```
>
> The resulting sequence may be empty if the hasNext predicate does not
> hold on the seed value. Otherwise the first element will be the
> supplied seed value, the next element (if present) will be the result
> of applying the `next` *function* to the seed value, and so on iteratively
> until the `hasNext` *predicate* indicates that the ***stream should
> terminate***.

So basically the first argument of the `iterate()` *seed* corresponds to the *initialization expression* of the `for` loop, the second argument (*predicate*) acts as the *termination expression* and the third argument (*unary operator*) plays the role of the *increment expression* ([*see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)).

#### Examples

Let's have a look at the couple of examples:

```
Iterator<String> iter = List.of("A", "B", "C").iterator();

Stream.iterate(iter.next(), str -> iter.hasNext(), str -> iter.next())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which is does the same as:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "dummy")
    .map(str -> iter.next()) // requesting the element
    .peek(str -> System.out.println(str + " <- invoking next()"))
    .takeWhile(str -> {
        boolean result = iter.hasNext(); // checking whether the next element exists
        System.out.println(result + " <- invoking hasNext()");
        return result;
    })
    .forEach(str -> System.out.println(str + " <- has reached the terminal operation\n"));
```

*Output of the second stream:*

```
A <- invoking next()
true <- invoking hasNext()
A <- has reached the terminal operation

B <- invoking next()
true <- invoking hasNext()
B <- has reached the terminal operation

C <- invoking next()
false <- invoking hasNext()
```

Let's explore all actions:

- The *seed* `iter.next()` will retrieve the first element `A` (in the second stream it will be done by the `map` operation). Then the *predicate* `iter.next()` would be triggered.
- Then the second element `B` would be retrieved, and the predicate will come into play.
- Then the third element `C` would follow, and  the predicate `iter.next()` will return `false` because the source was already exhausted.

**Conclusion** : in both cases, the last element `C` gets grabbed from the source before the *predicate* gets executed and since the source is already empty the *predicate* would be evaluated to `false` and this element would be thrown away.

#### How to fix it?

To make it successfully retrieve all the elements from the source, you need to swap the `map` and `takeWhile`, i.e. first check whether there's a *next element* and only then request the *next element*:

```
Iterator<String> iter = List.of("A", "B", "C").iterator();

Stream.generate(() -> "dummy")
    .takeWhile(str -> iter.hasNext())
    .map(str -> iter.next())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
A
B
C
```

This fix is only applicable with combination `takeWhile` + `map`, but we can't change the behavior of the `iterate()`.

---

As *@Slow* has mentioned in the comments, if you make the `SlidingWindows` class implement [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#method-summary) interface, then you can make use of the [`StreamSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) utility class that will take care of translating all the elements into a stream for you as it has been described here: [Why does Iterable not provide stream() and parallelStream() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23177907/17949945)

Note that it also requires transforming the *iterator* into an instance of `Spliterator` which can be done by utilizing the static method [`spliteratorUnknownSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliteratorUnknownSize(java.util.Iterator,int)) of the `Spliterators` utility class.

```
StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iter, Spliterator.ORDERED), 
        false) // a flag that denotes whether the stream should be parallel
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What is equivalent to the below code in Streams?

 ` while(slidingWindows.hasNext())
        {
            final String next = slidingWindows.next();
            log.info("{}", next);
        }`

Comment: @AneeshMohan0 You mean how to achieve behavior of the while loop? I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @AneeshMohan0 I think the solution you mentioned in your question is the "stream equivalent" of the `while` loop you want. Though your `SlidingWindows` class is an `Iterator` in spirit, if not actually one, so perhaps you could make use of that (e.g., [How to convert an Iterator to a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511052/how-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-stream)).